# Cannot Delete Tmp File in Pictures Folder

Tags: settings, insider-preview, storage, system-apps

I have this file since several months ago, and now my phone is running out of memory. The size of the file is not growing or decreasing. But, it is really annoying because it has 433Mb size and exists in my internal storage->Pictures folder, and I cannot delete it.
[image: tmp file in internal storage]
I have tried to delete it using phone's file explorer and via PC, the file is deleted, but suddenly this file came back.
My phone is Lumia 820 and running on OS build `10.0.10586.107`
How do I delete this file? If the file is a system file, then why it have to take place in "Pictures" folder?

Comment: Have you noticed any pattern to how this file comes back? If it's in the Pictures folder, it might be camera-related. Does it reappear after you record some video, perhaps? Also, check in Settings -> System -> Storage -> This Device, delete temporary files from there and see if it gets rid of the file.

Comment: @Indrek `Settings -> System -> Storage -> This Device` doesn't group that `tmp` file into `temporary files`, instead it is categorized as `Pictures`. I've tried clearing temporary files but I've got no luck. The file 'just come back' after I delete it, without open any apps.

Comment: Can you check the file extension ? And can you search for the app which can open it?

Comment: @User5 the extension of the file (as I checked in properties) is `tmp` file. You should know that `tmp` file could be 'anything', there's no specific application to open it.